# java.lang.IllegalStateException at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteResponseFacade.setBufferSize

Tags: java, jsf, illegalstateexception

I have a Java application runnning on a Glassfish server using JSF 2.0.2.

at JSF level I have the following method call.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{printWB.doOpenVehicleToPrintInPDF}" target="_blank">Print</h:commandLink>
```

My method **doOpenVehicleToPrintInPDF** is defined as follows:

```
public String doOpenVehicleToPrintInPDF() {
    FacesContext ctxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ctxt.getExternalContext().getResponse();       

    try {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + configUrl + ".pdf\"");

        final ServletOutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();

        final VehiclePrintSummaryToPdf vehiclePrintPdf = new VehiclePrintSummaryToPdf(ctxt, summary);
        vehiclePrintPdf.createPdfDocument(stream, summary);
        stream.flush();
        Validate.isTrue(response.isCommitted());
        stream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       LOG.error("Error in PDF print processing!", ex);            
    }
    return null;
}
```

The method is called, the PDF is generated (using the itext library) and afterwards the exception below is thrown. I've debugged this and the exception comes after the **return null;**

Any hint what is wrong here and how to avoid this exception?

Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteResponseFacade.setBufferSize(CoyoteResponseFacade.java:260)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.setResponseBufferSize(ExternalContextImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingSt
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.jav
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.bmw.codis.ncc.web.entrypoint.EntryServletFilterNCC.doFilter(EntryServletFilterNCC.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:599)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:92)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:34
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
```

Comment: what I don't understand is, why do you have a return type "String", but you will always return "null"?

Comment: @Dorin: returning `null` signals JSF that it should postback to the same view. Returning `void` does the same and is cleaner IMO.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you, didn't knew, I thought the issue lies there somehow...

Comment: No, your concrete problem is that you didn't tell JSF that you have already taken over the response handling to avoid that it continues into the render response phase. How to solve it is already been answered twice. Returning `String` or `void` doesn't matter here. It's just a style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSF lifecycle is attempting to write to a closed stream during its render phase. To prevent this, you must call [`responseComplete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) on the `FacesContext`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are generating the content yourself in a action method then you should signal to the jsf implementation that you did so. This should be done by calling [responseComplete](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) on the FacesContext.